# If $A$ is nipotent, how to prove that $A+A^*$ is not nilpotent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

If $A\neq0$ is nipotent, how to prove that $A+A^*$ is not nilpotent?

$A,A^*$ are nilpotent, but I have no idea how to continue

Comment: The statement is false. Let $A$ be the null matrix.

Comment: @89085731 : Is $A^*$ the adjoint of $A$?

Answer (score 4):

$A + A^*$ is Hermitian, and therefore diagonalizable.  A diagonalizable matrix is nilpotent if and only if it is zero.

Suppose, then, that $A + A^* = 0$.  That would mean that $A$ is skew-Hermitian.  However, a skew-Hermitian matrix is complex-diagonalizable, and is therefore nilpotent if and only if it is zero.  So, we conclude that $A = 0$.

Thus, if $A$ is nilpotent and $A+A^*$ is nilpotent, then we must have $A = 0$.